# Не могу установить ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Не могу установить модуль. Пишет это

> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

ввожу эту команду

```
pip3 install pyTelegramBotAPI
```

Answer (score 0):

Скачал репозиторий с гитхаба установил и сделал файл внутри него, все работает